# BIOS is not detecting any devices

Tags: boot, bios, hp-pavilion

A day before yesterday my hp245g5 notebook throwing an error on startup `Hard Disk error 3f0` `No boot device found on the hard disk`. In order to solve this I created a bootable flash drive and tried to boot my PC but it didn't detect any of the devices.

**What I've already tried?**

1. Disabled Secure Boot and enabled legacy support
2. Loaded setup defaults
3. Restored the security settings

After lot of googling, I still can't find a proper solution. Below are pictures of my BIOS settings.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GepC.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gP2h.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXMWt.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGA2c.jpg

These are some questions that I've already checked but can't find a solution.

- [Hard drive is not detected in BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/685182/hard-drive-is-not-detected-in-bios)
- [BIOS Sata ODD not detected](https://superuser.com/questions/928404/bios-sata-odd-not-detected)
- [BIOS not detecting working SATA hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/111477/bios-not-detecting-working-sata-hard-drive)
- [Samsung Series 5 BIOS not detecting any bootable devices](https://superuser.com/questions/680830/samsung-series-5-bios-not-detecting-any-bootable-devices)

In past I've accidentally cleared the `secure boot keys database`, I guess which may create some problems. And the option `Load Default Keys` do nothing, keys database always remains empty.

*Is this a MotherBoard issue?*

Comment: try booting linux OS from the pendrive...if that loads then it is not a motherboard issue....also open your notebook one time and check if the hard disk is proberly fit.....and if not linux then you could try to make a bootable of HIRENS Boot CD...which contains a ton of tools.

Comment: @Elmo A motherboard can still  boot a live session and at the same  time all or most of the devices connected to it can be faulty. Also it may boot any USB and have its own sata controller fried.  The only useful information you get is the motherboard isn't entirely fried.

Comment: Anandesh, Do definitely try out this tool as well: https://neosmart.net/EasyRE/
Might help in any errors you have been getting.

Comment: First I wanna thank you guys! Actually none of the devices are detected by BIOS whether its hdd, USB, DVD, etc. So how I can do this?